# How to add a protocol which contains associatedtype as a property in another protocol?

Tags: swift

I need to add a protocol which contains associatedtype as a property in another protocol, such like:

ProtocolA (contains associatedtype)

```
public protocol ProtocolA {
    associatedtype T
    func func1() -> T
}
```

And I want to have another protocol contains a ProtocolA object as a property, like this:

```
public protocol ProtocolB {
    var parameter: ProtocolA { get }
}
```

Then I got an issue from Xcode:

```
Protocol 'ProtocolA' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

I know I have to specific a type for ProtocolA's associatedtype, but how to do it?

Any idea will be appreciated

Comment: Add the `ProtocolA` requirement as an `associatedtype`: `associatedtype U: ProtocolA` and us `var parameter: U`

Comment: That's great, thanks a lot for your tips! @donnywals